# Qual é uma alternativa de criação de planilhas com números aleatórios em Python ? usando CSV

Tags: python

Ao criar planilhas com valores aleatórios em **Python**, fiz uso de um script contendo a biblioteca **openpyxl** (vide abaixo). Quero aumentar a velocidade de criação de planilhas aleatórias em python pois no método atual esta muito lento. **Como obter o mesmo resultado gerando CSV primeiro e separadamente?**

*O problema atual esta tanto no tempo gasto de criação dos arquivos*, quanto de memória RAM dedicada para montagem de cada planilha. A planilha, como configurado atualmente, traz como resultado aproximadamente 91,2 MB (95.674 kbytes) e esta demorando entre 400 e 700 segundos (dependendo de outros processos na máquina), bem como oscilando a memória RAM em torno de 8GB em cada ciclo.

**Pergunta:** Alguma sugestão (preferencialmente em código) com uso de CSV para supostamente aumentar a velocidade na geração das planilhas contendo números aleatório? Segue o código (ponto de partida) utilizado atualmente

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
import random
import time

def gera_plan():  
    print('start script')
    t = time.time()
    numFile = random.randint(1,1001)
    dest_filename = 'file_workbook_' + str(numFile)+'.xlsx'

    wb = Workbook()
    intro = wb.active
    intro.title = 'data'
    intro['B2'] = 'Just Confidencial Data'

    ws = {'ws1','ws2','ws3','ws4','ws5','ws6'}
    #for work in range(1,10):
    for work in ws:
        t_name = 'data'+str(random.randint(1,1001))
        work = wb.create_sheet(title=t_name)
        #work = wb.active
        for row in range(1, 5000):
            #ws1.append(range(random.randint(100,300)))
            work.append(random.sample(range(1, 10000), 600))
    wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
    print('end script')
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print('time %f seg' % elapsed) 

for ger in range(1,5):
    print('cicle:'+ str(ger))
    gera_plan()
```

Comment: Para evitar estender a discussão nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87546/discussion-on-question-by-cbe-user-99263-uma-alternativa-de-criacao-de-planilhas) e pode continuar normalmente lá, basta clicar no link.